# How to fix 'Cookie file /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie must be accessible by owner only' error in windows server 2019 with DockerProvider service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, windows-server-2019, rabbitmq-management

I'm installed docker in windows server 2019 with `DockerProvider`
I'm using this code

```
Install-Module DockerProvider
Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerProvider -RequiredVersion preview
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LCOW_SUPPORTED", "1", "Machine")
```

after that I install `Docker-Compose` with this code

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.0/docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\docker-compose.exe
```

after that I use a docker compose file

```
version: "3.5"

services:


  rabbitmq:
    # restart: always
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - myname
    # network_mode: host
    volumes: 
      - rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq



networks:
  myname:
    name: myname-network

volumes:
  rabbitmq:
    driver: local
```

everything is Ok up to here
but after i call `http://localhost:15672/` url in my browser
rabbitmq crashes and I see this error in `docker logs <container-id>`

```
Cookie file /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie must be accessible by owner only
```

this `.yml` file is working correctly in `docker for windows`
but after running the file in windows server, I see this error

Comment: change erlang cookie file permission to 400.

Answer (score 16):

Solution is to map a different volume where the cookie file will be created;

- https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/issues/171#issuecomment-316302131

So for your example, not;

```yaml
- rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
```

but;

```yaml
- rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
```

Comment: Thank you, this also fixes the issue with a volume mounted on Windows Dev Drive which is based on ReFS that is also used by Windows Server since Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 7):

You also have the option to overwrite the `command` of the docker image to fix the issue it is complaining about. Assuming that your cookie file is `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie`, replace the original docker image command, which is probably:

```
["rabbitmq-server"]
```

with:

```
["bash", "-c", "chmod 400 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie; rabbitmq-server"]
```

In your docker-compose file it will look like this:

```
...
image: rabbitmq:3-management
...
ports:
- "5672:5672"
- "15672:15672"
volumes:
- ...
command: ["bash", "-c", "chmod 400 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie; rabbitmq-server"]
```

Of course, you introduce here some workaround/technical debt that you assume `rabbitmq-server` will stay like that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I deleted the previous file .erlang.cookie

```
ls -al
128 Apr  4 10:55 .
384 Apr  4 10:55 ..
 20 Apr  4 02:00 .erlang.cookie <= delete this 
192 Apr  4 10:55 mnesia
```

and restart docker (or nerdctl) compose

Answer (score 0):

found `.erlang.cookie` file in your host directory, then type `chmod 400 .erlang.cookie` and restart rabbitmq docker, it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This issue showed up suddenly after I changed the dir/file permissions recursively on my Linux VM where Anylogic Cloud is running.
This is how I fixed it.

1. docker inspect rabbitmq
2. Find the host directory for /var/lib/rabbitmq from the output of inspect.
   For example
   "Type": "bind",
   "Source": "/xx/xx/rabbitmq",
   "Destination": "/var/lib/rabbitmq",
3. Navigate to the actual host directory/location and execute 'ls -al' command. It should list the cookie file.
   -rwxrwxrwx  1     Feb  8 16:00 .erlang.cookie
4. Then type chmod 400 .erlang.cookie.
   You may restart rabbitmq container.

Answer (score -1):

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq1/data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
      - ./rabbitmq1/config:/etc/rabbitmq
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "rabbitcookie"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "admin"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "password"
    networks:
      rabbitmq-cluster:

networks:
  rabbitmq-cluster:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my verified config file

If you want to see the verification results, please see here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtSwz.png)

Comment: @liuchanglong I copied your image's relevant part into the answer, please verify it is as you intended and remove the image.